# URL Wildcard Redirect via htaccess parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect this URL:

```
http://example.com/?p=*
```

to

```
http://example.com
```

tried many codes but not works

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?p=.*$ /
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=.
RewriteRule ^$ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What about showing "some" of the codes you have tried?

Comment: post edited . I have tried many codes but cant redirect url includes tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use with `?` alone:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Or last line with [QSD]. This flag (query string discard) is available in version 2.4.0 and later.

```
RewriteRule ^$ / [QSD,L,R=301]
```